# bash + verify results from output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I need to find if resource is not online according to the following rules

in case of Resource name is on both machines machine1 and machine2 then one of them should be online , otherwise need print resource is down

in case of  Resource name is only on one machine machine1 or machine2 then status should be on line , otherwise need print resource is down

any idea how to implement this with bash or awk ? or perl one liner ?

```
Resource name   machine name   status


more file.txt

nis-master      machine1       Stop
OnGuard-a       machine1       Online
nis-slave       machine2       Offline
OnGuard-b       machine2       Offline
oracle-vip      machine1       Online
oracle-vip      machine2       Offline
oracle-disks    machine1       Online
oracle-disks    machine2       Offline
oracle-res      machine1       Stop
oracle-res      machine2       Offline
oracle-cluster  machine1       Online
oracle-cluster  machine2       Offline
```

example - resource is on both machines ( no need to print resource is down )

```
Resource: oracle-vip machine1 Online
Resource: oracle-vip machine2 Offline
```

example - resource is on one machine ( need to print resource is down )

```
Resource: nis-master machine1 Stop
```

example - resource is on both machines ( need to print resource is down )

```
Resource: oracle-vip machine1 Offline
Resource: oracle-vip machine2 Offline
```

**meanwhile** I write the following code ( in bash ) , but maybe someone can improve it to better short solution

```
   FIRST_LINE=` awk '{print $1}' file.txt  | grep -v Resource `
   for i in $FIRST_LINE
   > do
   > [[ ` grep -c $i file.txt ` -eq 1 ]] && [[ ` grep $i  file.txt | awk '{print $3}' | grep -c Online ` -eq 0 ]] && echo $i no online
   > [[ ` grep -c $i file.txt ` -eq 2 ]] && [[ ` grep $i  file.txt | awk '{print $3}' | grep -c Online ` -eq 0 ]] && echo $i no online
   > done



  nis-master no online
  nis-slave no online
  OnGuard-b no online
  oracle-res no online
  oracle-res no online
```

Comment: You have asked [many questions in awk](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2557854+is%3Aquestion+[awk]). I would expect you to be at least able to write some pseudocode. What have you tried so far? Also, do not cross post: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158580/bash-verify-results-from-output

Comment: hi fedorqui - I have answer for this question please realse this question so I will answer please

Comment: you can edit your original post improving the approach and indicating what you have. Eventually, it will get reopened. Check: [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)

Comment: ok see my update question - hope its good for you so please reopen the question .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you could do it using awk:

```
awk '{seen[$1]} $3 == "Online" {online[$1]}
     END {for(i in seen)if(!(i in online)) print i ": resource is down"}' file
```

Add each filename to the `seen` array. Add the names of files with "Online" in the third column to the `online` array. After processing the file, go through the list of all the files and print the ones that weren't in the `online` array.

Testing it out on your file:

```
$ awk '{seen[$1]}$3 == "Online" {online[$1]}END{for(i in seen)if(!(i in online)) print i ": resource is down"}' file
oracle-res: resource is down
OnGuard-b: resource is down
nis-master: resource is down
nis-slave: resource is down
```

Comment: +1 for you I will check that - I will return if it work on my machine - thx

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I think your question needs some more tidying up (in particular the formatting). Once you do that, I'm sure that you will be upvoted.

Comment: great thx again on your solution , I will keep in my mind your words -:)